# Hooking Into File Upload Progress Shown In Browser

Tags: html, upload, progress

I've been looking for a way to track upload progress for a file server, and noticed at the bottom of Google Chrome it had a bar in the bottom left-hand corner showing where it was at percentage-wise. (See below). Is there a way to hook into this and retrieve its value as a variable? Is there a certain way Chrome is generating this number? Is this specific to Chrome?

[image]